# Backlight can't be adjusted 13.04

Tags: 13.04, laptop, brightness

In Ubuntu 12.04 i was able to change the brightness of my laptop screen by using the FN + Rightarrow

all i had to do for that was include

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor pcie_aspm=force"
```

in /etc/defaults/grub

however this does not work anymore now. i do not know where to look any further (2h of googling haven't brought up anything yet...)

can you help?

Comment: Please provide details as to your laptop make/model also.  There are some proprietary hardware configurations by certain vendors that alter the potential solution you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same problem with 13.04.
If you want, you can adjust it through the system settingss --> brightness and lock.
I don't have  fix for  det shortcut..

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to map your keys to XF86MonBrightnessUp and XF86MonBrightnessDown using xmodmap. You'll need to determine which "keymap" value corresponds to your arrow keys.

For now checkout `xmodmap --help` and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap

To see if you have anything mapped to XF86MonBrightnessUp open a terminal and enter:
`xmodmap -pke | grep -i bri`

If you map the keys and it still doesn't work, it's possible that there is a proprietary hardware issue as suggested by gravity in comments above.

I'll look at this later to see if I can improve this answer.